# Spotlight Search Plugin VIM

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin

I am looking for a way to hit a hotkey and then search for a file in the directory I am. Something that is like spotlight search for MACS. Currently, I am using NERDTree and I love it. Now I just need a way to quickly switch between files. I have a lot of subfolders so it is troublesome especially when things need to be quick. If there were some way to map a hotkey and bring up a search bar that searches the root folder I am currently in that would be so awesome.

TL;DR

I want a plugin that I can use to search for files within vim that is accessed by a hotkey and can open the file.

Does anyone know of such wizardry?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the built-in `:edit` or `:find` or any of their relatives?

Comment: ctrlp is the plugin you're looking for https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

Comment: ctrlp is pretty good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ctrlp` plugin to have this function.

> https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim

Just enter ctrl + p, then search the name of file :D